# Update grid from a query

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a Visual Basic 2010 application that uses a `DataGridView` to display a list of frequencies from a Microsoft Access 2010 database. The application uses the `BindingNavigationPostionItem` to allow navigation though the table.

The *Move Next* and *Move Previous* buttons move you up and down the list. The cool thing is, as you do this, I have code that sends the `Frequency` and `Mode` to my Yeasu radio and the radio then is set to that freq/mode.

This works great but, if I try to filter the `DataGridView` by the `Service` field, the `ID` field becomes blank and navigation does not work.

Here is the code that runs after you select what you want to filter by and you click the filter button:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmbox1 As String
    cmbox1 = ComboBox1.Text

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from HFUtil where service = '" & cmbox1 & "'", MyConn) ' 
    da.Fill(ds, "HFUtil")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))


    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = source1

    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    BindingNavigator1.Refresh()
    '=========================================================        
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Text = ""

    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim sItemTemp As String
        sItemTemp = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", dr("freq"), dr("mode"), dr("desc"))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(sItemTemp)

    Next

    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox2.Text = ""
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

        Dim sItemTemp As String
        sItemTemp = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", dr("freq"), dr("mode"), dr("desc"))
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(sItemTemp)

    Next

End Sub
```

The only difference between this code and the code that runs on form load is - where clause in the data adapter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see in your code where you apply your filter. So, lets pretend for a second that you load your whole table into `DataSet`. Then next thing, you either use `DataSet.DefaultView` or create your custom `DataView` and assign this to `DataSource` property - you did this.

Now, all you have to do is apply row filter to the data view you use

```
view.RowFilter = "service = '" & cmbox1 & "'"
```

At this point you should only see subset of records and nothing should happen to your `Id` field. Because your data doesn't change.

I have suspicion, you changing your view somewhere and this is why you have problems.